# Swift 5: saving complex objects to file storage

Tags: ios, swift, file-storage

I am working on a school assignment for which I have to develop an iOS application in Swift 5. The application needs to utilize a web service (a web-API) and either file storage or user defaults.

I had chosen to develop a "QR code manager", in which users can create QR codes for a URL by setting a few design parameters, which are then sent to a generator API. This API (upon an OK request) returns an image in a specified format (PNG in my case).

I have a class with the URL and all the design properties of the QR code, which will also contain the image itself. Please see below code snippet for the class.

```swift
public class QRCode {
    
    var bsId : Int?
    var url : String?
    var name: String?
    var frame: Frame?
    var logo: QrCodeLogo?
    var marker: Marker?
    var color : String?
    var bgColor : String?
    var image : Data?
    
    
    init(data: [String:String]) {
        self.url = data["url"]
        self.frame = Frame.allCases.first(where: { $0.description == data["frame"] })
        self.logo = QrCodeLogo.allCases.first(where: { $0.description == data["logo"] })
        self.marker = Marker.allCases.first(where: { $0.description == data["marker"] })
        self.bgColor = data["backGroundColor"]
        self.color = data["colorLight"]
    }
    
    init(json: String) {
        // todo
    }
}

extension QRCode {
    func toDict() -> [String:Any] {
        var dict = [String:Any]();
        let otherSelf = Mirror(reflecting: self);
        for child in otherSelf.children {
            if let key = child.label {
                dict[key] = child.value;
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }
}
```

All the properties are nullable for ease of development, the class will be further refactored once I have successfully implemented everything.

I have tried various methods I found all over the internet, one of which can be found in the class extension. The function `toDict()` translates the object properties and their values to a `Dictionary` object of type `[String:Any]`. However, I read that when the `Any` datatype is encoded and then decoded, Swift cannot determine which complex datatype the decoded data is supposed to be, effectively rendering the data either meaningless or unusable.

Another method I found was through extending the `Codable`-protocol in the class. As far as I am aware however, `Codable` only accepts primitive datatypes.

Please find below my currently written code for file storage handling. It is not complete yet, but I felt it was a good start and might help in this question.

```swift
class StorageManager {
    
    fileprivate let filemanager: FileManager = FileManager.default;
    
    fileprivate func filePath(forKey key: String) -> URL? {
        guard let docURL = filemanager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first else {
            return nil;
        }
        
        return docURL.appendingPathComponent(key);
    }
    
    func writeToStorage(identifier: String, data: QRCode) -> Void {
        guard let path = filePath(forKey: identifier) else {
            throw ApplicationErrors.runtimeError("Something went wrong writing the file to storage");
        }
        
        let dict = data.toDict();
        // TODO:: Implement
    }
    
    func readFromStorage(identifier: String) -> Any {
        // TODO:: Implement
        return 0;
    }
    
    func readAllFromStorage() throws -> [URL] {
        let docsURL = filemanager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0];
        
        do {
            let fileURLs = try filemanager.contentsOfDirectory(at: docsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil);
            
            return fileURLs;
        } catch {
            throw ApplicationErrors.runtimeError("Something went wrong retrieving the files from \(docsURL.path): \(error.localizedDescription)");
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to Swift and I am running stuck on file storage. Is there any way I could store instances of this class in file storage in such a way that I could reïnstantiate this class when I retrieve the data?

Thanks in advance! Please do not hesitate to ask any questions if there are any.

### Edit

Based on matt's comment, please find below the code snippets of the `Marker`, `Frame`, and `QrCodeLogo` enums.
The `Frame` enum:

```swift
public enum Frame: String, CaseIterable {
    case noFrame
    case bottomFrame
    case bottomTooltip
    case topHeader
    static var count: Int { return 4 }
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .noFrame:
            return "no-frame"
        case .bottomFrame:
            return "bottom-frame"
        case .bottomTooltip:
            return "bottom-tooltip"
        case .topHeader:
            return "top-header"
        }
    }
}
```

The `QrCodeLogo` enum:

```swift
public enum QrCodeLogo: String, CaseIterable {
    case noLogo
    case scanMe
    case scanMeSquare
    static var count: Int { return 3 }
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .noLogo:
            return "no-logo"
        case .scanMe:
            return "scan-me"
        case .scanMeSquare:
            return "scan-me-square"
        }
    }
}
```

The `Marker` enum:

```swift
public enum Marker: String, CaseIterable {
    case version1
    case version2
    case version3
    case version4
    case version5
    case version6
    case version7
    case version8
    case version9
    case version10
    case version11
    case version12
    case version13
    case version15
    case version16
    static var count: Int { return 15 }
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .version1:
            return "version1"
        case .version2:
            return "version2"
        case .version3:
            return "version3"
        case .version4:
            return "version4"
        case .version5:
            return "version5"
        case .version6:
            return "version6"
        case .version7:
            return "version7"
        case .version8:
            return "version8"
        case .version9:
            return "version9"
        case .version10:
            return "version10"
        case .version11:
            return "version11"
        case .version12:
            return "version12"
        case .version13:
            return "version13"
        case .version15:
            return "version15"
        case .version16:
            return "version16"
        }
    }
}
```

All the above enums contain the valid design options for the API I use. They serve as an input restriction to prevent "invalid parameter"-errors from occurring.

Hopefully, this clears things up.

Thanks again!

Comment: “As far as I am aware however, Codable only accepts primitive datatypes.” Not true. Anything with codable properties is codable. So just make your frame, marker, and logo types codable. But you have not explained what the frame, marker, and logo types _are_, so impossible to help.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the quick comment! The Frame, Marker, and Logo types are enums containing the design options allowed by the API I use. A restriction to minimize the risk of "invalid parameter"-errors occurring. The enums extend the CaseIterable class, so each case has a "description" property, which returns a string containing the valid parameter for the API. I'll include them in the post with explanation.

Comment: I would also ask: is there a really good reason for using Optionals for your properties?

Comment: Also is there a really good reason for your weird `init(data:)`? Why don't you have a normal memberwise initializer?

Comment: On your comment about enums being Codable: For some reason, the XCode IntelliSense kept saying I was not conforming to the Codable protocol until I removed the enums and replaced them with primitive datatypes. What should I do in order to have them Codable? I included the enums in the post now.

Comment: @matt About the optionals, for a while I was not sure exactly what the response from the API would be (the docs were not very clear on that), so I made the properties optional in case I would not always receive the same response. Now I realize the response is nothing but an image, so there is no reason for the properties to be nullable anymore. Which also renders the weird `init(data:)` unneccessary. I realize now that it was unneccessary anyway, I found it tricky to find consistency in forums about how to go about problems in Swift.

Comment: To make an enum codable, declare it to be Codable. — By the way, your `description` for all your enums is unnecessary, as it is the same as the built-in `rawValue`. Just use an equal sign to set the string value of all the cases directly.

Comment: Also if you make your class Codable you won't need that initializer to populate it from the API, as you can just use its Codable powers to initialize it directly from the JSON. That is one of the main points of Codable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type can conform to Codable provided all its properties conform to Codable. All of your properties *do* conform to Codable except for the enums, and they will conform to Codable if you declare that they do. Thus, this simple sketch of your types compiles:

```
public enum Frame: String, Codable {
    case noFrame
    case bottomFrame
    case bottomTooltip
    case topHeader
}
public enum QrCodeLogo: String, Codable {
    case noLogo
    case scanMe
    case scanMeSquare
}
public enum Marker: String, Codable {
    case version1
    case version2
    case version3
    case version4
    case version5
    case version6
    case version7
    case version8
    case version9
    case version10
    case version11
    case version12
    case version13
    case version15
    case version16
}
public class QRCode : Codable {
    var bsId : Int?
    var url : String?
    var name: String?
    var frame: Frame?
    var logo: QrCodeLogo?
    var marker: Marker?
    var color : String?
    var bgColor : String?
    var image : Data?
}
```

There are many, many other things about your code that could be improved.
You don't need CaseIterable or `description` for anything. Now that your type is Codable, you can use *it* to retrieve the values from JSON directly, automatically. If the names of your enum cases do not match the corresponding JSON keys, just make a CodingKey nested enum to act as a bridge.

In other words, being Codable makes your type *both* populatable directly from the JSON *and* serializable to disk.